# Applying Velocity to a node over a CGVector value 1200 makes it disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

In SpriteKit I have it set up so that when the fallingBlocks hit the sliderNode they disappear and reappear with a new velocity, but when the velocity is over a 1200 value, the node doesn't appear.

I've tried integer, float, double, long double, and they've has the same result. When you 1999.99 the node appears. This is the code I use to apply the velocity:

```
fallingBlockNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1200.0);
```

I can post screenshots of the app if you need to see what I mean by the node disappearing. It is not the zPosition being changed as I have already tried that. In the debugger, when the velocity is over 1200, the node isn't even added to the view.

Comment: 1200 is too fast. Chances are the the node's distance covered by one update exceeds the screen size.

Comment: What do you mean by "When you 1999.99..."?

Comment: 1999.99 would be the value input instead of the 1200. Like this fallingBlockNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1999.9);